# Guessing Game Questions

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

Guessing game that I got from a youtube video and wanted to ask a few questions that I didn't get. One what is the point of the else outofGuesses=1 part? Secondly when do you use one equal sign and when to use 2. Last but not least was there an easier way to do this like using a for statement?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void) 
{
    int secretNumber= 5;   
    int guess; 
    int guessCount=0; 
    int guessLimit=3;
    int outofGuesses=0; 

    while(guess !=secretNumber && outofGuesses ==0)
    { 
        if(guessCount< guessLimit)
        { 
            printf("Enter a number between 1 and 10:"); 
            scanf("%d", &guess); 
            guessCount++; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            outofGuesses =1; 
        } 
    } 
    if(outofGuesses==1) 
    { 
        printf("You lost!");
    } 
    else
    { 
        printf("You win!");  
        return 0;   
    } 
}
```

Comment: what happens to the while loop when outofGuesses  becomes 1? One = sign means "store this value in the memory location with the name before the = sign. Two = signs means "is the right side of the == equal to the left side of the ==?

Answer (score 1):

All of that is extremely basic, and if you have to ask, then you should look for a better teacher/tutorial

= is used to assign a value to a variable.

== is used to compare two values.

outofguesses=1 assigns the value 1 to that variable when you run out of guesses; it causes the comparison inside the 'while' to fail and the program flow to skip it to the finishing portion.

Answer (score 1):

## What is the point of the else outofGuesses=1 part?

It is meant to be a flag or an indicator. In this case, 1 represents true and 0 represents false

---

## When do you use one equal sign and when to use 2?

As pointed out by @am121 in the other answer, use `=` for assigning a value to a variable and `==` while checking if two values are equal

---

## Was there an easier way to do this like using a for statement?

First off, the program has a bug. The variable `guess` is not initialized and has undefined behavior. For example, if the `guess` is same as `secretNumber`, the person wins the game without playing. For this program, it should be assigned any value NOT equal to secret number

Same thing using for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int secretNumber= 5;   
    int guess = 0; //Some value not equal to secretNumber 
    int guessLimit=3;

    for(int guessCount=1; guess!=secretNumber && guessCount<=guessLimit; guessCount++){ 
        printf("Enter a number between 1 and 10:"); 
        scanf("%d", &guess);             
    } 

    if(guess == secretNumber)
    { 
        printf("You win!");
    } 
    else
    {
        printf("You lost!");
    }
}
```

Comment: When making an int like int guess in this example do you always have to set it equal to something? Thank you for answering and showing the for statement.

Comment: You don't have to immediately set it to something. But it has to be set before it is used. In the question, it was being used before being assigned a value. So you can't be certain what value it has and it causes undefined behavior